How can i copy a disk snapshot to an Azure container using either az cli or azure portal?
I have a vm disk snapshot and am trying to copy it to an Azure Container.
How do i do this manually using the Azure Portal ?
I have tried to do it using az cli as follows:


$subscriptionId="<subscriptionId>"
    $resourceGroupName=myResourceGroupName
    $snapshotName=mySnapshotName
    $sasExpiryDuration=3600
    $storageAccountName=mystorageaccountname


    $storageContainerName=mystoragecontainername

#Provide the key of the storage account where you want to copy snapshot. 
    $storageAccountKey=mystorageaccountkey

#Provide the name of the VHD file to which snapshot will be copied.
    $destinationVHDFileName=myvhdfilename

   az account set --subscription $subscriptionId

   $sas=$(az snapshot grant-access --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $snapshotName --duration-in-seconds $sasExpiryDuration --query [accessSas] -o tsv)

az storage blob copy start --destination-blob $destinationVHDFileName --destination-container $storageContainerName --account-name $storageAccountName --account-key $storageAccountKey --source-uri $sas



But it doesnt seem to copy gives error:
ERROR: unrecognized arguments: https://..... 

I assume that is for the --source-uri ?
How can i copy a disk snapshot in a resource group to an Azure Container ?

It seems the error you are encountered due to --source-uri is handled in the CLI.
You can ensure that the $sas variable contains the full URL, including the https:// prefix, before executing the az storage blob copy start command.
Here is the updated Azure CLI script to copy the Snapshot to Azure Container.
$subscriptionId="8332bf56-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-a507-d7e60e5f09a9"
$resourceGroupName="VM-RG"
$snapshotName="Venkat-VM-os-snapshot"
$sasExpiryDuration=3600
$storageAccountName="vmstoragevhdtest"
$storageContainerName="vmstorage"
$storageAccountKey="hR1tvnvnvnfnffnggR42vpuBqiqzIo+uYJTMKFbvA=="
$destinationVHDFileName="venkatosdisk.vhd"

az account set --subscription $subscriptionId

$sas=$(az snapshot grant-access --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $snapshotName --duration-in-seconds $sasExpiryDuration --query accessSas -o tsv)

az storage blob copy start --destination-blob $destinationVHDFileName --destination-container $storageContainerName --account-name $storageAccountName --account-key $storageAccountKey --source-uri $sas

Output
After executing the azure cli script, the snapshot has been copied to azure storage container.

Reference: az storage blob copy start

it gives error on az storage blob copy start,   z : ERROR: Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.

in this line $sas=$(az snapshot grant-access --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $snapshotName --duration-in-seconds $sasExpiryDuration --query accessSas -o tsv),   is the resourcegroupname the name where the storage account is ?

For generating snapshot export URL, its not require Storage account details.

I geta $sas , but the next line fails with that error

the storage account and snapshot lie in different resource groups

If you are running in local PowerShell, can you try in Azure Cloud shell.

az storage blob copy start --account-name "vmstoragevhdtest" --destination-blob "venkatosdi.vhd" --destination-container "vmstorage" --account-key "" --source-uri ""

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

storageAccountKey i got by going into the storage account and Access Keys . I picked the key 1 Key.

FYI code/data/script should not be in comments. Further, comments are not the place for lengthy discussions.

How should I respond if op/someone asks a question after I have posted the answer?

@VenkatV - The OP shouldn't be asking new questions in comments - if anything, they should update their question with more detail, if they've done something in addition.

I suggest he seek help if he continues to ask the same questions, such as "Is the script working?"

Still it didnt work... I need to do manually which takes forever ?

Hi @Sandy, Please try the same script in Azure Cloud Shell if it is not working in local PowerShell.

it was to do with the $sas, it did not have quotes around it.. I get the same as you , status:pending.   But when i look at the container it says Blob Type is "Page blob" , is that correct ? Also the size is 1TiB , is that 1 terra byte ?

How can i check the status of the copy to make sure it is done as i want to do a second process once it is finished ?

i did , az storage blob show .... to see the status. It said "failed". Now it is a VM Disk which is quite large , about 1 Terra Byte . How can i make sure it is copied or just do it manually instead , which is better ?
